# Java: object assign

Tags: java, object, reference

I though in java, when you do `object1=object2`, you will copy the reference of `object2` to `object1`, so `object1` and `object2` point" to the same object. Is it right?

I wrote a function to sort a stack.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class sortStack {

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        s.push(2);
        s.push(21);
        s.push(43);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(87);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(12);
        s.push(10);
        s.push(25);
        sortStack(s);

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(s.pop() + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void sortStack(Stack<Integer> src) {
        Stack<Integer> dst = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> buf = new Stack<Integer>();//buffer

        while (!src.isEmpty()) {
            int v = src.pop();
            if (dst.isEmpty()) {
                dst.push(v);
            }

            while (!dst.isEmpty() && dst.peek() > v) {
                buf.push(dst.pop());
            }

            dst.push(v);
            while (!buf.isEmpty()) {
                dst.push(buf.pop());
            }
        }
        src = dst;

        //Print:
        //while(!src.isEmpty()){
        //  System.out.print(src.pop()+" ");
        //}
    }
}
```

I couldn't get any output from the class. If I uncomment the print part, it words fine.
I don't understand the `s` stack is empty after I call the function. I already assign `dst` to s, so s should point to the `dst` stack, right?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: A stack is normally used for FILO operations (first-in-last-out). Why not use simple sortable collections like `ArrayList`?

Comment: Relevant: Java is not pass-by-reference. It's strictly pass by value, only some values happen to be object references. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @MenoHochschild The question not allow to use ArrayList. It's like an Interview question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are assigning a reference to a parameter, src, which is in fact a local variable, and hence you're not seeing any effect on the original Stack variable, s. Instead have the method return dst and assign the object returned. i.e.,

```
public static Stack<Integer> sortStack(Stack<Integer> src) {
    // ....

   return dst;
}
```

and

```
s = sortStack(s);
```

Answer (score 6):

When you set `src=dst` you are only overwriting the local copy of the reference within the method. In the process of calling the method local copies are made of each parameter, such that within your method *modifying src through its methods* would have an effect outside the method but *assigning src to a new reference like dst* would not.

Your code will work if you `return dst` in `sortStack` and put `s = sortStack(s)` in your calling function.